# Check a webform on clientside with RegularExpression if it contains two or more words

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to get a RegularExpression to work in my webform (working in MVC) on the client side so it validates that the user inputs two or more words. Since it's firstname and surname I would like it to accepts letters like "åäö" as well (doesn't have to be just åäö, all letter are fine).

I did this code:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Du måste fylla i ditt namn"),
 RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z]*(\s[A-Za-z]*)+$", ErrorMessage = "Du måste skriva både för- och efternamn"),
 Display(Name = "Namn")]
 public string Name { get; set; }
```

I know the code above only will accept A-Z and that is the problem for me. I tried like this instead but it still doesn't pass a name like "Örjan Sörensson":

```
RegularExpression(@"((^[\w]*\s[\w]*).*)+$", ErrorMessage = "Du måste skriva både för- och efternamn"),
```

The result I'm looking for is something like:

- "Olle Svensson" => pass
- "Åsa Äng" => Pass
- "Sören Höre" => Pass
- "Olle " => Fail
- "Åsa" => Fail

Comment: Go with `^\p{L}+(?: \p{L}+)*$`

Comment: On client side, the pattern should be JS compatible. I'd suugest to limit to server side validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the initial range `[A-Za-z]` is not *wide enough* (since you have letters with *diacritics* like `Å`, `Ä`); try `\p{L}` which matches any letter:

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
     "Olle Svensson",
     "Åsa Äng",
     "Sören Höre",
     "Olle ",           // should fail: one word only followed by space
     "Åsa",             // should fail: one word only
     "Örjan Sörensson"
  };

  string pattern = @"^\p{L}+(\s+\p{L}+)+$";

  var results = tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,-20} {(Regex.IsMatch(test, pattern) ? "Pass" : "Fail")}");

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, results));
```

Outcome

```
Olle Svensson        Pass
Åsa Äng              Pass
Sören Höre           Pass
Olle                 Fail
Åsa                  Fail
Örjan Sörensson      Pass
```

So the attribute can be

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\p{L}+(\s+\p{L}+)+$", 
                    ErrorMessage = "Du måste skriva både för- och efternamn")]
```